# RDP Connection fails on certain setup

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I have a set of boxes at my disposal running Win 2k8R2 that I regularly need to connect to using Win RDP from my local workstation that is running XP.  We are in the middle of a migration to Win7 as our main workstations, so as part of the test we run the RDP to connect to our boxes.  When attempting the connection from the Win7 worskstation two of the three machines is perfectly fine to connect to, but the other states

> "This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connecting
>   again.
>
> If the problem persists, contact the owner of the remote
>   computer or your network administrator."

We have tested many different aspects:

- We are able to ping from any machine, XP, W7 & 2k8R2 using both FQDN & IP address
- We have tested connection from different machines:
  XP works; Win 7 fails, 2k8R2 fails.

  - Interestingly a colleague in a different team has a Win 7 workstation and shouldn't be able to connect to this machine but can.
- We have run Tracert to see if it could be a network issue, but both XP and W7 run through the same local DNS server

The three remote servers are in the same domain and all have the same settings in the Remote Settings and Firewall; these are set by Group Policy when setting up the machines, and Firewall cannot be turned off as other pages have suggested would be a good point for testing.

- We have restarted the machine and the related services.
- We have tried connecting from different machines but nothing changes.
- I have looked through the Microsoft help pages and can say that with the way can or cannot connect that nothing in there fits the issue that we are facing.

We can say that incoming RDP connections work, so there isn't any major setting. The outgoing RDP connections work from the W7 machine so that isn't the problem either. Connecting from W7/2k8R2 to this particular server is causing a lot of headaches, even though we can make just about any other connection, even outgoing from the problem server.

We have contacted our main sysadmins and tech help but the best they were able to suggest was to restart.  The Network team passed it to Wintel, who said it was a network problem.

If anyone can provide some assistance it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Remote Desktop Gateways or are you connecting to RDP straight through? What does the event log on the server side have to say about your connection attempt - can you see any errors or warnings logged?

Comment: We're using standard Windows Remote Desktop Connection.  The target server has no items in Event Viewer relating to this issue, even keeping it open while recreating the error to see if events were generated by it, but nothing